# TwitterKit - TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource Search Query Formatting

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

I am retrieving and displaying a list of tweets in a table view. The following code grabs a bunch of tweets from a search and displays them. This works fine!

```
 Twitter.sharedInstance().logInGuestWithCompletion { session, error in
        if let _ = session {
            let client = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
            self.dataSource = TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource(searchQuery: "cats", APIClient: client)
        } else {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

However, when I change the search query in order to get tweets referring to a specific user, I just get a blank screen.

```
 Twitter.sharedInstance().logInGuestWithCompletion { session, error in
        if let _ = session {
            let client = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient
            self.dataSource = TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource(searchQuery: "@mtasummit", APIClient: client)
        } else {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

I've trying to encode the '@' symbol a couple of ways, and that didn't seem to work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overlooked a small detail in the API:

"Also note that the search results at twitter.com may return historical results while the Search API usually only serves tweets from the past week." (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

The reason I was not seeing any tweets, was because my search term "@mtasummit" only contained results several months old, so they weren't being retrieved.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In 2k17 I found this "Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week." here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets